# json.stringify output is 1023 character...why ?

Tags: json, limit, stringify

i have a little big problem, my javascript object is too long, but it is ok.
at the moment i use .stringify() function for convert my object in a json string, the string is truncated with "..." and the lenght is 1023.

why ?
 AND how change this limit ?

im sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3):

The RFC for JSON parsers (see http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt section 4) says, each implementation may choose to limit the length and content of strings.  So depending on which browser / version you are using at the moment, you may be hitting the limit.

One portable alternative would be to look at json2.  The JS source is found at https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js -- you could use this as-is, or alter it to deal with the length / type of data that's causing your problem.