# How to extend the JSON.Stringify() limitation, inorder to convert large javascript array to JSON string?

Tags: javascript, json

`JSON.Stringify()` can only convert 1023 characters, if my javascript array has large amount of data, then how do I convert it to JSON object?

Comment: see answer in duplicate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211620/json-stringify-output-is-1023-character-why

Comment: I have yet to see a 1023 character limit for stringify, and I have used very large data sets. Can you give an example of how you are getting this?

Comment: Hello All, It was while debugging the json string was getting truncated and not actually with JSON.stringify(). Thank you all for your response.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var first, y, i$, ref$, len$, toString$ = {}.toString;
switch (toString$.call(x).slice(8, -1)) {
case 'Object':
  fs.writeFileSync(output, '{');
  first = true;
  for (y in x) {
    if (x.hasOwnProperty(y)) {
      if (first) {
        first = false;
      } else {
        fs.appendFileSync(output, ',');
      }
      fs.appendFileSync(output, JSON.stringify(y) + ':' + JSON.stringify(x[y]));
    }
  }
  fs.appendFileSync(output, '}');
  break;
case 'Array':
  fs.writeFileSync(output, '[');
  first = true;
  for (i$ = 0, len$ = (ref$ = x).length; i$ < len$; ++i$) {
    y = ref$[i$];
    if (first) {
      first = false;
    } else {
      fs.appendFileSync(output, ',');
    }
    fs.appendFileSync(output, JSON.stringify(y));
  }
  fs.appendFileSync(output, ']');
  break;
default:
  fs.writeFileSync(output, JSON.stringify(x));
}
```