# NodeJs : Invalid string length

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

So basically I've been working on "stringifiying" a huge data using Json.stringify function :

```
var json = Json.stringify(data)
```

but i got some  error about string length :

```
exception RangeError: Invalid string length
```

is there any alternative function similar to Json.stringify to do this job for a huge data .

Comment: can you put your json?

Comment: sorry no , it's so huge (10MB)

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211620/json-stringify-output-is-1023-character-why