# AJAX call returns 403 when array sent exceeds specific length

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I've some jQuery code sending data through an AJAX call to a PHP script.

Data consists of an object with two properties.

One of the properties is a string, obtained by `JSON.strinfigy(arrayofobjects)` an array of objects.
Each object in `arrayofobjects` contains 3 properties, each being a simple string.
The number of objects in `arrayofobjects` is variable based on some user actions.

The problem is: when `arrayofobjects` exceeds the number of 25 objects the AJAX call fails and returns `403 Forbidden`, so any debug is impossible.

It seems like the string resulting from `JSON.stringify` and sent through AJAX ovverides a maximum length.

The web server is Apache2 running on Ubuntu 18.04.
Not using any PHP framework.

What I have tried:

- Apache mod_security module is not active
- In php.ini: display_errors = On, log_errors = On and error_reporting = E_ALL
- Set write permissions for every user on apache2/error.log
- Regular working apache2/error.log, but no trace of AJAX-related issue, no trace of any `403` error
- URL of called script is correct
- It's not a cross-domain call
- File permissions are OK since the script is called successfully in other instances and when `arrayofobjects` contains less than 25 elements
- I can access the called page directly through http
- Increased `max_input_vars` value in `php.ini`

The structure of AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
url: "ajax/called_page.php",
type: 'post',
data: {action: "post_duty", content: JSON.stringify(arrayofobjects)},
dataType: "json",
success: function(data) {
 do some DOM manipulation
}, error: function() {
 alert('Contact webmaster');
}
```

Comment: In your ajax : `error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(jqXHR);  console.log(textStatus); console.log(errorThrown); }` can help debugging

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666256/jquery-ajax-call-results-in-error-status-403

Comment: If you are using a php framework, such as Symfony, you should check the logs of that framework too (Symfony logs are in `/var/logs`

Comment: @Casper this is not a CORS request

Comment: How do you know: "when arrayofobjects exceeds the number of 25 objects the AJAX call fails" is true?

Comment: @Cid I'm not using any PHP framework

Comment: @HerrWalter this post triggered me to think about the array length, so I tried to extend `arrayofobjects` up until 25 elements, that's when the call fails.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211620/json-stringify-output-is-1023-character-why

Comment: @Cid tried debugging using your code, but it's not returning anything more than what I get using browser developer tools

Comment: Please check your file/folder permission.